# Increasing Overdischarge Protection Voltage in DW01A

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, lipo, over-voltage-protection

I am working on a academic project which requires TP4056 along with battery protection circuit (DW01A).

The ciruit uses a 1S LiPo 500mAh battery.

I want to keep the Overdischarge Protection Voltage (VODP) to 3.2v. Looking at the datasheet of DW01A-G, it mentions that VODP is typically 2.4v.

https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/DW01x-DS-17_EN_53550.pdf

Can i increase the VODP by simply increasing the resisor value R2 which is shown in the typical application circuit?

I did search for other posts in SE but didn't find any convincing answers. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot change any threshold for this chip designed to maximize battery capacity at the expense of aging rate or cycle life.

VODP threshold has a laser trimmed (variable) resistor inside the chip and is not externally accessible.

Comment: I am using a 1S LiPo 500 mAH. Can you recommend any IC which has VODP of 3v to 3.2v. I found another IC FS312F-G by the same manufacturer which has a VODP of 2.90±0.080 
http://ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/FS312F-G-DS-12_EN.pdf